# How to fix ER_PARSE_ERROR in node.js using express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm setting up a crud in node.js using express and i have completed create and update but i still stuck in delete function

i tried to analyse the code from the handlebars and the route of /delete but still couldn't figure out why the user_id cannot be read

user_list_view.hbs:

```
<form id="add-row-form" action="/delete" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="DeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Product</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <strong>Do you want to delete this data ?</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control user_id" required>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery in user_list_view.js:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytable').on('click','.delete',function(){
        var user_id = $(this).data('user_id');
        $('#DeleteModal').modal('show');
        $('.user_id').val(user_id);
    });
})
```

process.js:

```
router.post('/delete', (req,res) => {
let sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id="+req.body.user_id
let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.redirect('/user_list')
 })
})


module.exports = router
```

I expected the result to delete the selected user based on the user_id but i got the error message:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
errno: 1064,
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near ''at line 1",
sqlState: '42000',
index: 0,
sql: 'DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! latihan3@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Comment: My best guess is that `req.body.user_id` is blank which is why in your error message `'DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id='` is missing the right-hand expression of the `user_id=`. So the sql statement is incomplete. Ensure you are passing the user_id in the post request.

Comment: @marshy101 isn't that `req.body.user_id` got the `user_id` from `input type="hidden" name="user_id" class="form-control user_id" required>` in `user_list_view.hbs` ?

Comment: Yes, but you also need the body-parser middleware for express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .query syntax for mysql it takes 2 params but the first is your query the second would be params, not a callback. Unless you have it wrapped to work that way.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connector-nodejs-promise-api/

`// DON'T HAVE TO DO THIS "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id="+req.body.user_id`

`let query = db.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=,[req.body.user_id]).then(results => {
    if (err) throw err
    res.redirect('/user_list')
 })`